# How to send events from Lightning page to VisualForce page iframe

Tags: visualforce, lightning, event, iframe

I've got a VisualForce page inside a Lightning page, and as it does, the VisualForce page is wrapped into an iframe when it's rendered on the Lightning page. I need to figure out how to communicate from the Lightning Page (parent) to the VisualForce page in the iframe. Is there a pattern for that where I can avoid the Cross Origin issues?